# iOS - Find out for which account App Store has paid the developer?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to find out for which account**(s)** App Store has paid the developer?

For eg:

- I have an app for $10
- 1 user bought app in June
- Apple paid developer $7 in July

Can I find out via `API` which user was it via some field like `Transaction Receipt` or something?

Comment: No. Apple does not give developers any user details. Thankfully Apple has some respect for user privacy.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification.